# How to use LinQ lambda expression in Azure Function and it's connected with Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

Here is my issue.I have Azure Function and it's connected with Azure SQL ok.
I have 1 table is A in Azure SQL

A => Id | name 
with value is
      1 | Duc

When I try to use LinQ in azure function like

```
    var x="";
    int i=1;
    using(MyDB db=new MyDB())
    {
       x=db.A.where(x=>x.Id == i).select(x=>x.name).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I want it show "x = Duc".But it don't show anything?.

My AzureFunction was deployed by VS 2017 with version

net461
 v1

Thanks for read.

Comment: You're reading the name of the `FirstOrDefault()` result with the query, but you're never using any output for `x`. Also, questions are: What is your MyDB? Is it an EF context? And if so, where does it get its connection string? Is that OK? Does the query actually run? Is the result you're expecting to be there actually there, or does `FirstOrDefault()` return null? So many questions...

Comment: Tks u for answe @rickvdboschr,this codes works fine on my locally.But when I deploy in azure function,it don't show anything.In locally,the query actually run.My connectionString works fine too.My connectString when local is connected with SQL server.When I deploy to Azure Function,I connect with SQL Azure similar my SQL server in local.And that LINQ can't use anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better provide more details, like your data mapping class and the details in the function.cs.

To make sure  the connection string is correctly used, you can use log.Info(connectionstring) to check if it's used correctly.

I did a test with the following simple code, and the data can be fetched correctly from azure sql database.(VS 2017 and function v1 net461 ).

step 1: create a table in azure database:
[image]

step 2:Create a azure function v1 project:

2.1:The following is database mapping code, add an new .cs file named test:

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace FunctionApp11
{
    [Table(Name ="test")]
    public class test
    {
        private short _id;
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_id")]
        public short id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._id;
            }
            set
            {
                this._id = value;
            }

        }

        private string _name;
        [Column(Storage = "_name")]
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return this._name;
            }
            set
            {
                this._name = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

2.2:The code in Function class(I just use hard code for the connection string):

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace FunctionApp11
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {                        
            string str = "Server=tcp:your_server_name.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=your_db_name;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user_name;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
            int i = 3;

            DataContext db = new DataContext(str);
            Table<test> students = db.GetTable<test>();            
            var query = students.Where(x => x.id == i).Select(x => x.name).FirstOrDefault();

            log.Info($"the first student is:{query}");

            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

3.Publish to azure, and start to run, you can see the data is fetched.
[image]

Comment: OMG,I will try it,tks u very much